# Toshiba Qosmio: Battery Stuck at 60%, does not Charges, PC can't power up, can't remain on with out AC adapter

Tags: battery, battery-life

Just like the tittle says, now let me try to give some more detail about the symptoms;

The battery is stuck at 60 percent (68% at the moment of this writing).When hovering over the battery icon in Windows 7 Home Premium x64 it reads:"68% available (plugged in, charging)", there's no x or any sing the OS is displaying any error. No matter how much time left connected to the AC adapter the battery doesn't charge, it seems however it continues to discharge at its normal rate when disconnected from the laptop (about 1% each 2 weeks).
Now this last symptom is the one i find most strange it "seems" the laptop somehow isn't recognizing the battery because even with the remaining charge of 60%(ish) the laptop wont power up or remain on if disconnected from its AC adapter(if it's on and is unplugged it will immediately turn off). Meaning that even with the battery attached correctly in its right place is as if running the laptop with no battery at all.

Toshiba's Utilities haven't detected anything strange (or anything for that matter) with the battery or the hardware.
The laptop when in use is connected 90% of the time to a Belkin surge protector (like my 1TB EHD). The protector is working correctly (green light on) and the 1TB HD too, thus  a power surge having damaged it's very unlikely.

Thnx in advance

Edit: I forgot to mention that the laptop and the power surge protector were bought fairly recently, last year's mid december

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a lot of laptops lately  with this problem. Remove the battery and clean the contacts on both the battery and the laptop with a stiff, dry toothbrush. Put the battery back in and see if this doesn't help.